# SOQL to find out all users that comes under the Profile = XYZ?

Tags: soql

SOQL to find out all users that comes under the Profile = XYZ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its good practice for someone new to refer the [SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) and share what you have tried so far.

To filter by-

1. Profile Id:

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ProfileId = 'XXXX'
   ```
2. Profile Name:

   ```
   SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
   ```

Note: Add more fields to SELECT clause to retrieve the data.

Also learn more on awesome [trailhead site](https://trailhead.salesforce.com):

1. [Write Your First SOQL Query](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/transform-sql-queries-to-soql-queries-in-a-lightning-app/steps/write-your-first-soql-query)
2. [Execute SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/developer_console/units/developer_console_queries)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get profile information from user object. Each user has its own profile.that should be mandatory field as well.

***Execute below query in Query Editor***

```
   select id,name,profile.name from user where profile.name='XYZ'
```